# pointer arithmetic in C++ using char*

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm having trouble understanding what the difference between these two code snippets is:

```
// out is of type char* of size N*D
// N, D are of type int


for (int i=0; i!=N; i++){
    if (i % 1000 == 0){
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    }
    for (int j=0; j!=D; j++) {
        out[i*D + j] = 5;
    }
}
```

This code runs fine, even for very big data sets (N=100000, D=30000). From what I understand about pointer arithmetic, this should give the same result:

```
for (int i=0; i!=N; i++){
    if (i % 1000 == 0){
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    }
    char* out2 = &out[i*D];
    for (int j=0; j!=D; j++) {
        out2[j] = 5;
    }
}
```

However, the latter does not work (it freezes at index 143886 - I think it segfaults, but I'm not 100% sure as I'm not used to developing on windows) for a very big data set and I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious about how pointer arithmetic works. Could it be related to advancing char*?

**EDIT:** We have now established that the problem was an overflow of the index (i.e. (i*D + j) >= 2^32), so using uint64_t instead of int32_t fixed the problem. What's still unclear to me is why the first above case would run through, while the other one segfaults.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: What is the type of `D` variable?

Comment: you should show the declaration of out rather than a comment

Comment: I'm certainly hoping the `out` array size is at least `D + D*N`, or you're walking in memory you don't own.

Comment: out is passed into the function where the above block of code lives, the declaration is a bit more involved as out is initialized as a numpy array out = np.zeros((N,d), dtype=np.int8, order="F") and then wrapped in a cython script.

Comment: You're doing this calculation on a 2.793GB array of chars?  I rather think that's not optimal.  Wait, this is O(N^2) with a flush in the outer loop?  That'd take many many days to run

Comment: @Mooing Duck: It's a mid to large sized data sets you often encounter in biology, on modern hardware this runs in rather quickly (roughly 200s).

Comment: @soramimo: I assure you, the only explanation for the posted code being _fast_ is because it's _wrong_.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Just copying a chunk on memory is VERY FAST. This code snippet runs in O(N*D), which in practice boils down to 60 seconds for D=300k, N=15k. If you care to elaborate why you think the code is "wrong", please go ahead.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Why do you think the size should be D+D*N? The size is D*N and this is sufficient, correct?

Comment: (1) it assigns data to the first third of the data twice, he middle third once, and he last third not at all.  Thats wrong.  (2) It also appears to try to assign data to D elements past the end of the array, which is a completely unrelated way his code is wrong

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't understand either of your claims. Assuming that the overflow is fixed now, I double loop over i and j, writing exactly once to out[i*D + j] for each pair (i,j). Second, out is initialized to be of size N*D. The last index of i is (N-1) so there are D elements to be written to complete the full N*D array. I think your claim that elements are written beyond the end is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, using `uint64_t` for `i*D+j` would fix the first problem with your code.  Also, I just did the math again, and realized I was wrong, I thought you were writing an "extra row" to your data, but I was incorrect.  My bad on that second one.  I'm not sure why you're seeing a segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`N * D` is 3e9; that doesn't fit in a 32 bit `int`.

Comment: I started thinking about this just now, I think this is the reason!

Comment: I'm on a 64bit machine, I assume I can just fix this by using int64 for N, D instead of int32?

Comment: And how does this work: `out[i*D + j] = 5;`? It was my first guess until I saw that.

Comment: @soramimo If you are overflowing, you are overflowing with the same values, right? Blah, just try it, I am waiting to see the accepted answer here for 30 minutes :).

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: Yes, his code assigns the value five to the first 2e9 cells, and then assigns the value five to the first 1e9 _again_, leaving the last 1e9 unset.

Comment: @Alan Stokes: This reply certainly fixed my problem, thank you for this. Also, I think we've established what happens when the index overflows in case 1. However, it still escapes me why case 1 did in fact run through, while case 2 did not, any ideas?

Comment: The only way to know for sure would be to look at the generated code. The compiler must be optimising in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

When using N as size of array, why use int? 
does a negative value of an array has any logical meaning?

what do you mean "doesn't work"?

just think of pointers as addresses in memory and not as 'objects'.

```
char* 
void*
int*
```

are all pointers to memory addresses, and so are exactly the same, when are defined or passes into a function.

```
char * a;
int* b = (char*)a;
void* c = (void*)b;
```

a == b == c;

The difference is that when accessing a, a[i], the value that is retrieved is the next sizeof(*a) bytes from the address a.

And when using ++ to advance a pointer the address that the pointer is set to is advanced by

```
sizeof(pointer_type) bytes.
```

Example:

```
char* a = 1;
a++;
```

a is now 2.

```
((int*)a)++;
```

a is now 6.

Another thing:

```
char* a = 10;
char* b = a + 10;

&(a[10]) == b
```

because in the end

```
a[10] == *((char*)(a + 10))
```

so there should not be a problem with array sizes in your example, because the two examples are the same.

EDIT

Now note that there is not a negative memory address so accessing an array with a signed negative value will convert the value to positive.

```
int a = -5;
char* data;
data[a] == data[MAX_INT - 5]
```

For that reason it might be that (when using sign values as array sizes!) your two examples will actually not get the same result.

Answer (score -1):

**Version 1**

```
for (int i=0; i!=N; i++) // i starts at 0 and increments until N.  Note:  If you ever skip N, it will loop forever.  You should do < N or <= N instead
{
    if (i % 1000 == 0) // if i is a multiple of 1000
    {
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl; // print i
    }

    for (int j=0; j!=D; j++) // same as with i, only j is going to D (same problem, should be < or <=)
    {
        out[i*D + j] = 5; // this is a way of faking a 2D array by making a large 1D array and doing the math yourself to offset the placement
    }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
for (int i=0; i!=N; i++) // same as before
{
    if (i % 1000 == 0) // same as before
    {
        std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl; // same as before
    }

    char* out2 = &out[i*D]; // store the location of out[i*D]
    for (int j=0; j!=D; j++) 
    {
        out2[j] = 5; // set out[i*D+j] = 5;
    }
}
```

They are doing the same thing, but if `out` is not large enough, they will both behave in an undefined manner (and likely crash).

Comment: I'm not sure who is down-rating this, but it is accurate.

Comment: Hi Zac, out is actually N*D in size, so it should be large enough. The problem seems to be in fact that int32 isn't enough to hold the index.

Comment: That is A problem with it, but it is far from the ONLY problem with the posted code.

Comment: And given that your first statement is, "I'm having trouble understanding what the difference between these two code snippets is ..."  the explanation that they are doing the same thing is correct.  Both will screw up equally when you attempt to overflow an int32.

Comment: you're right, they both produce unexpected results, however in a different way. While using uint64_t instead of int32_t in fact solved my problem, the reason for the different behavior of the two cases still escapes me.

Comment: Different way?  The both suffer from an overflow.  You get slightly different behavior because you are in the realm of undefined behavior.